# Why do Chrome developer tools and actual Chrome rendering differ?

Tags: css, google-chrome, jquery-mobile, google-chrome-devtools

I've posted an image of what my Chrome debug tools look like on a fairly standard JQuery Mobile page.  I've already figured out that it actually isn't using the :visited style because none of the links are actually visited.  I didn't have an :active style so the links were still blue.  So I know what I need to do to fix it, but that's not my question.  My question is why is it telling me that it is using that style when it is not?  Is this a Chrome bug or am I reading the tool wrong?

[image]

Comment: Collapse the tree below `<a>`. Do you see any other elements, e.g. `<span>`?

Comment: Yes there is a an `<img` tag and it does have the following style `.ui-body-c .ui-link:visited { color: #2489ce; }` JQuery Mobile styles sure are strange.  That does seem to be the issue.

Comment: After refreshing it is again showing the same gray visited style on both the a tag and the img tag.  So there is still discrepancy between the actual color and the color be shown as active in the debug tool.

Comment: What I have discovered is the developer tool is show :visited as the active style even though that isn't correct.  If I change the actual active style that is crossed out, the style is changed to the correct color, but the developer tool still shows :visited as the active style when it is not.  The only conclusion I can come to is that this is a developer tool bug.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the total inheritence of all classes. To see what final properties are being applied clicked on "computed"

Also this looks like JQUERY mobile so I suspect you are going to run into some issues of very large class paths that are not easy to detect. I posted a few of these up here - one in particular about styling buttons.